# What are conventional file name extensions for Fortran namelists?

Tags: fortran, filenames

I've seen and used the file name extension `.in` for Fortran namelist files used in my personal codes. I've also seen in several instances within Fortran language documentation that uses the `.DAT` extension. Now I'm working on a commercial code that will generate and use its own namelist file, and I'm wondering if there are conventions for Fortran namelist file names. If so, what?

Comment: This probably belongs somewhere else. It is opinion based. You can use whatever you want, `.nml`, `.conf.`, `.cfg`, `.ini`...

Comment: @VladimirF "opinion based" is not a reason to ask a question at Programmers: we have the same "primarily opinion-based" close reason there as here. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: @Snowman I have no idea how you managed to see a very first version of my comment when the grace perioid is over for some 7 minutes.

Comment: @VladimirF original version of your comment has been posted by a [special bot](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7154/31260) to [Programmers chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23196383#23196383)

Comment: Well, they should probably read the comments twice, before reacting, @Snowman

Comment: @VladimirF I would say that my question is experience based - not opinion based. I understand my question is subjective, in that the file name extension can be anything, but that does not mean there are not conventions such as those listed in the first comment. I believe my question meets most, if not all, of the guidelines for asking subjective questions listed in http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I think that the question might be off-topic but definitely not opinion-based. It is asking for conventional practice. It happens almost all the time time on SO that comments ask to people to follow conventions when writing their code.

Comment: Going back to the question itself, I do not know if people agree on standard to name those files. I usually do not add extensions to mine. I name them like "xxx_namelist". some collaborators do not like it but at the end of the day they are happy with it, because the name say what it is. I do this because I learned the namelist accidentally from a guy who had only one in each of his project and simply named it "namelist". As I am thinking about it, I will start naming them "xxx.namelist", it is a kind of cool extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard like this. Even organizations which do use namelists extensively and do have written coding coventions do not prescribe any suffix for namelist files, e.g., http://research.metoffice.gov.uk/research/nwp/numerical/fortran90/f90_standards.html

or

http://www.easterbrook.ca/steve/2010/11/climate-model-coding-standards/ (I did not go through all of them, it is for your reference)

(I would add that namelist usage *is* farely common in meteorology.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no well-established widely-used naming conventions for files containing Fortran namelists. You are free to choose your own - use your freedom wisely.

I'd go a bit further, namelists themselves seem to be neither widely-used nor well-established in Fortran-ville.